# Working version of SDWebImage

Tags: sdwebimage

I accidentally deleted my old SDWebImage version from my project and now I need to readd it again. The newest versions can be added as a framework to Xcode, but that doesn't work, because if I do that, I get linker errors left and right.

So it would be good if I simply had the working sourcecode. But if I download the sourcecode from the github page and add it to my project, I am getting errors that some properties are not synthesized or not declared.

Where can I get the latest working sourcecode for SDWebImage?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the "SDWebImage" folder, downloaded from [Github](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/tree/master/SDWebImage)

If the current version isn't working, you could try an [older commit](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/tree/e3d8bc8daf537a7b23f67f25dacac876aa18bdc7/SDWebImage), but I find SDWebImage to be a bit buggy. It would be better to figure out why the current version isn't working and fix that. Open another question giving details of what's going wrong when you add the current version.

Comment: The latest code from the Github repo is not working, as I have undeclared identifiers and unsynthesized properties in it.

Comment: @user975561 I added some details to my answer.

Comment: Alright, new question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874918/problems-with-current-version-of-sdwebimage