# Problems with current version of SDWebImage

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, sdwebimage

When I download the latest sourcecode of SDWebImage from the GitHub repo, I get compile errors in it.

For example in SDImageCache.m I have undeclared or unsynthesized properties. In initwithNameSpace: a variable named _ioQueue is used, but it is not declared anywhere and some others.

Same is in SDWebImageManager.m in its init method. It uses an undeclared variable named _imageCache. There is more of this.

Where can I download the latest working code of this project?

Comment: So it turns out alle the sourcecode I download has some snythesize statements missing. What is going on here?

Comment: I can only guess that you are using an older version of xcode/compiler. Newer version does not require @synthesize of properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using iOS 5 for my project. It turned out that the new versions of the library are made for iOS 6. So I had to find a version which worked on iOS 5. I downloaded it, included it and it is working again.